# Three detectmultiscale methods in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

What is the difference among detectMultiScale, detectMultiScale2, and detectMultiScale?
How do you select the rihght method?

http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/objdetect/CascadeClassifier.html#detectMultiScale

Regards,
Fukuhara Yohei

Comment: Each one is same, only changes with parameters. its related to your parameter.

Comment: Thank you!
I was afraid if some process of the method is different.